# How to use pkill -STOP -f process in python2?

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I have a project in python2 to stop and resume processes by name. I tried `os.system("pkill -STOP -f  'processA'")` and  also `os.system("pkill -CONT -f  'processA'")` in order to continue the process while processA is defined inside the same python2 file.

(the problem is that the command did not run as defined in the python2 file it did not do anything to the processA that was defined.)

what I need is a way to put what is defined inside the command.
let's imagine that:

```
processA = "bash"
os.system("pkill -STOP -f {processA}")
```

**Is there a way like that to put what is defined inside the command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should define the full command for os.system in the form of

```
cmd = "pkill -STOP -f " +(processA)
```

then print it by the following:

```
print(cmd)
```

So, if we combine it all the result will be:

```
import os
processA = "bash"

cmd = "pkill -STOP -f " +(processA)
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

and this is the best answer because it defines the full command that is wanted for os.system in order to run **processA** with the command **pkill**.

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if you edited it to explain why it is correct and why it is the best answer for the question, so that others can learn from your knowledge.